# How to create a project from another one stored in SVN?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, svn, spring-tool-suite, spring-4

I created a `Spring legacy` project from `Spring Tool Suite`, it is a `Spring-MVC` project. I deposited my project into a Linux Ubuntu server where there is `SVN` installed. Now my coworker wants to work on the same project with me. So how to import the project into him ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you checked your project into SVN somehow (using the command-line interface, a SVN client, or a plugin for Eclipse), someone else on your team should be able to check out the project in the same way.

In case you are looking for a Subversion integration for Eclipse/STS, please go to the Eclipse Marketplace and install an SVN integration from there. You can find the Marketplace entry in Eclipse/STS in the "Help" menu.